# Node.js SlowBuffer detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I added an xor method to the buffer class that make sure that `argument instanceof Buffer`. The `require('crypto')` has a method of randomBytes that gives an object that appears to be a slow buffer.

I am trying to allow xor method of Buffer to only allow Buffer objects and SlowBuffers, but `key instanceof SlowBuffer` gives an error. Does anyone know how I can detect if key is an instanceof SlowBuffer?

```
var key;
crypto.randomBytes(10,function(err,bytes) {
  key = bytes;
});
//key instanceof SlowBuffer
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. Does looking at the [crypto source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_crypto.cc) help?

Comment: Or the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)?

Comment: [Related](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs-dev/browse_thread/thread/7da5781df8f88da6)?

Comment: Also, what is the error that you get?

Comment: I managed to find where the SlowBuffer is located, my big problem was that there is a global called Buffer and there is a module called Buffer. The Module contains the definition for the SlowBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_isbuffer_obj `Buffer.isBuffer` method will return true for SlowBuffer and Buffer objects.